# Creating Session Expiration Limit in MVc 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery

I have a real time problem. I want to show the pop up to user after 4 minutes that your session is going to expire in next 1 minute. Please click continue to stay active and then ultimately increase the session time if user clicks on Continue. How can I achieve this in Asp.net MVC 3.0 without using  any third party Controls.

Comment: Start a sort of timer in js, after 4 minutes ask, if user click continue send an ajax call to a separate action to renew the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick sample, just put together from the w3c schools documentation. I guess there will be other approaches to this by using jQuery, SignalR etc, but you stated no third party controls.

```
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},240000);

function myTimer()
{
    // perform a reset when we enter the function
    window.clearInterval(myVar);

    var r=confirm("Session will expire in 1 minute. Click OK to stay.");
    if (r==true)
    {
        // perform ajax call to renew the session.
        // perform other task like refresh elements or even the page.

        // get response from ajax call, then restart the interval.
    }   
}
```

Comment: just tell me one thing please, how to resent a session. just to assign it a value will reset it and what I have to do in calncel so that it do not reset the Session. Please Suggest me.

Comment: That depends on how your are defining your session. Are you just relying on the built in session? That will renew the timer per request from the client(browser).

Comment: If I remember correctly, the default timespan for the session is 20 minutes.

Comment: yes Sir. Default is 20 minutes and I just set session like this. At login , i do  ::  Session["LoginID"]="Bla Bla";